# Where do I find Angular CLI 7.3.9 default generated webpack settings file so I can build my overrides based on it?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I want to extend webpack building process for a project generated by Angular CLI v7.3.9.

I found out I have to use this tool:
https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/7.x.x/packages/custom-webpack

It seems a good solution, but unfortunately I can't find any example about extending existing Angular CLI config file.

I mean - I want to see what Angular CLI already generates for me, before I can think of correct overrides I should use in my custom builder override config. Being somewhat new to webpack, I need to learn what's already there to be able to figure out what I can adjust to avoid totally breaking the project.

**Where do I find Angular CLI default generated webpack settings file so I can build my overrides based on it?**

To be more specific, the problem is that building the project for production takes about 25 minutes. It is a large project with a few hundreds of form and grid components, and I see that current build process is spending about 20 minutes in ModuleConcatenationPlugin and 5 minutes in TerserPlugin without any serious load on the computer resources. I've heard ModuleConcatenationPlugin is being deprecated and thought that maybe I could use something better instead (UglifyJS ? optimization.concatenateModules ?), but at first I have to find out how Angular CLI uses it, so I can override it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

technically in angular cli since v5 (as far as I know)  you have `ng eject` which will give you access to webpack config.

Comment: Unfortunately they have disabled `ng eject` in v7.

Comment: oh yeah you're right, seems like you can find them here : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/7.3.x/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngx-build-plus](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus)

Example:

- Add ngx-build-plus: `ng add ngx-build-plus`
- Add a file webpack.partial.js to the root of your (sub-)project:

```
     const webpack = require('webpack');

        module.exports = {
            plugins: [
                new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                    "VERSION": JSON.stringify("4711")
                })
            ]
        }
```

- Use the global variable VERSION in your app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare const VERSION: string;

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'Version: ' + VERSION;
}
```

- Start your application with the --extra-webpack-config switch pointing to your partial webpack config:

```
ng serve --extra-webpack-config webpack.partial.js -o
```

If your project is a CLI based sub project, use the --project switch too:

```
ng serve --project getting-started -o --extra-webpack-config webpack.partial.js
```

Update you can take a look at their [doc](https://angular.io/cli) and here is the full [config](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace)

Comment: It's similar to `custom-webpack` project but the problem remains the same - without knowing the original config, you cannot have clear idea what to override.

Comment: @JustAMartin check my answer again